# Accessing a service host from inside a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, host, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot config server running in localhost on port 8888. I'd like to access this service from inside a docker container. I cannot put this service inside the same docker-compose and in the same network.

Service: http://localhost:8888/cpo-executor/dev 
Using my ip: http://192.168.0.6:8888/cpo-executor/dev

I've checked this address on browser and it's working. When I try to access from inside a docker container I got an error:

```
docker exec -it 7febe846f2ea /bin/bash
curl http://192.168.0.6:8888/cpo-executor/dev
```

Error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.6 port 8888: Connection timed out
```

I've tried to start my containers putting "network_mode: host" in docker-compose but I ended up falling into another error, from one container not communicating with another.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql
```

How can I access a service from host from inside a docker container?

Comment: I assume `mysql` is another service defined in your docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what platform your Docker engine is running on.

1. On Windows, your containers can connect to host with special hostname `host.docker.internal` (see [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)). By contrast, `host` network mode does not work on Windows (see [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)).
2. On Linux, you should use `host` network mode. However, this will break how your containers connect to each other. In the default `bridge` network mode they can connect to each other by using hostname identical to the name of service (`mysql` in your case). With `Host` network mode however you should use `localhost` hostname instead, because all containers share the same host's networking.